# In Windows Server 2012 R2, why am I getting no option to add a website within IIS Manager?

Tags: windows, website, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

Our administrator created a new virtual machine with Windows Server 2012 R2 on it.  I'm trying to create a website in IIS, but there is no option to add a website within the IIS manager.  In the connections pane, all I have is a "Start Page" option, with menu options:

- Connect to a server
- Connect to a site
- Connect to an application

Online documentation expresses there should be an add web site feature, but it's not there.  I'm trying to explain to the admin why that is wrong, but I wanted to ask is that missing a windows feature, or permissions, or what am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there (IIS) Manager?? In the Server Manager, click the Tools menu, and then click Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager

Comment: Yes, the utility is there, but I have no permissions to do anything except to connect to another server or web site remotely.

Comment: You sure IIS Web Services are actually installed? Because it sounds like you have only management tools available.

Comment: No, I'm not sure... just have to get the right people to acknowledge the issue.  That's probably it, thanks.